# iOS Crash Reporting with Manual Uploads

Tags: ios, crash-reports

I'm working on an enterprise iOS app with the somewhat unusual use case of running almost exclusively in the background under various background modes.  We'd like to implement remote crash reporting into our app (we can't use iTunes Connect since it's not an App Store app) but the solutions we've been looking into all seem to send their crash logs the next time the app is launched into the foreground.  Obviously, this doesn't really work for us.

So, does anyone know of any crash reporting tools out there that are capable of uploading crash logs in the background or that allow the developer to manually trigger the upload when its good for us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bugsense (https://www.bugsense.com/) its very complete and you can configure to send the crash when occur or when the app starts

Comment: Even if the app is launched into the background?

Comment: I think it is transparent. It catch's the crash and store it or send it immediately (You can configure)

Comment: Cool!  I'll check it out and accept your answer if it pans out.  Thanks!

Comment: Finally got around to checking out BugSense and it looks like it will fit our needs well.  Thanks Maxado!